# определить к какой части речи относиться слово

Tags: php

Пишу генератор паролей на основе слов. Есть словарь откуда берутся рандомные слова. вот функция которая берет рандомное слово:

```
function getWord()                                                                                                   //Возврашает слово из словаря 
{
    $FILENAME = "slovar.txt"; //Имя файла
    $LINE_DELIMITER = "\n"; //Разделитель строк в файле
    $MAX_LINE_LEN = 255 + strlen($LINE_DELIMITER); //Максимальная разумная длина одной строки
    $TRIPLE_BUFFER = $MAX_LINE_LEN * 3; //Берем немного с запасом
    $fileLen = filesize($FILENAME); //Длина файла
    if (empty($fileLen) || $fileLen < $TRIPLE_BUFFER) { //На всякий случай проверим длину файла
       throw new \ErrorException("Файл слишком мал");
    }    
    $rnd = rand(0, $fileLen - $TRIPLE_BUFFER); //Случайная позиция для чтения
    $handle = fopen($FILENAME, "r"); //Открываем файл для чтения
    fseek($handle, $rnd); //Устанавливаем указатель в случайном месте файла
    $stream = fread($handle, $TRIPLE_BUFFER); //Читаем начиная со случайной позиции
    $lines = explode($LINE_DELIMITER, $stream); //Разбиваем текст на строки
    $lineCount = count($lines); //Считаем количество прочитанных строк
    $randomLine = ""; //Инициализируем нашу случайную строку
    $startAtLine = ($rnd !== 0) ? 1 : 0; //Пропускаем первую строку, так как она может быть обрезана
    for ($i = $startAtLine; $i < $lineCount; $i++) { //Ищем случайную строку
        if (!empty($lines[$i])) {       //Пропускаем пустые строки
            $randomLine = $lines[$i]; //Ну и наконец, вот наша случайная строка
            break;    
        }
    }

return $randomLine;  
}
```

А нужно чтобы она при определенных параметрах возращала либо существительное либо прилагательное, либо глагол

Существительные оканчиваются на "о" и "а", а прилагательное на "ый" "ая" "ое" "ые", глагол на "ть"
в итоге хочу сделать чтобы получались словосочетания :

```
*существительное* + *существительное* 

 *существительное* + *прилагательное* 

 *прилагательное* + *существительное*

 *существительное* + *глагол*
```

Comment: Слово "мать" заканчивается на "ть", но является существительным.

Comment: А слово "существительное" заканчивается на "ое", но тоже является существительным.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Реализация ужас. Кроме того очень рекомендуется использовать mb_strlen вместо strlen ибо в кодировке UTF-8 например strlen=255 не будет равняться 255 символам. Более правильная реализация:

```
mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");

$file=file("slovar.txt"); // создается массив из файла

$array = array_filter($file, function($val) {  // фильтруем массив
    if(mb_strlen($val)>10 && mb_strlen($val)<255 ){
        return " ".trim($val)." ";
    }
});

if (count($array)<10 || mb_strlen(implode('',$array))<1000) { // если меньше 10 строк или меньше 1000 символов
       throw new \ErrorException("Файл слишком мал");
}   

$randomLine=$array[array_rand($array,1)]; // возвращаем случайную строку

preg_match_all('/ ([^ ]{1,}ый) /ui', $randomLine, $words); // массив слов c окончанием "ый"

return echo $words[1][array_rand($words[1],1)]; // возвращаем случайное слово
```